# Odex file Vs dex file

Tags: android, dex

I am curious to know the differences between odex file and dex file. I searched on net but did not find enough information.Here are my questions

1. What is the purpose of odex file?
2. How can create odex file for my application?
3. If I create odex, will it be supported on all API levels?

Thanks,
Manan

Answer (score 3):

1. It's an app optimized code
2. You can do that on the device, you'll need the command line dexopt-wrapper and running something like dexopt-wrapper
3. Yes, but you don't have to create odex files the system does that by itself. Well, depends what you want to achieve actually.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer for question two:

How can create odex file for my application?

The "classes.dex" file is optimized to odex file automatically. If "xxx.apk" stores in `/data/app/xxx/xxx.apk`, then its "xxx.odex" will be stored in `/data/app/xxx/oat/arm/xxx.odex`.

I tested on Android 6.0.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to recreate an odex file, but here's a description.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-odex-and-deodex-in-android-complete-guide/